# Batch file is not being created in subfolder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, batch-file

I believe this code is correct, but I have created a temp folder in the c:\ and the batch file is not being created for some reason.. does anyone have suggestions?

```
var sText, s;
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


    if (!fso.FileExists("C:\\temp\\COO_BTO_Test.bat")) {
        s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\temp\\COO_BTO_Test.bat", true);
        sText = "@echo off";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":Lbl";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XA^MD0^PRB^JVY^LL1760^LH%XL%,%YL%^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,08^BY2,2.0,32^BCN,N,N,N^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,48^AF,8,8^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":END";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^PQ1     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XZ     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM MODE COM1 9600"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM TYPE COO.TXT > COM1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "TYPE COO.TXT > LPT1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);
        s.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Does the file already exist? Does the process have write access to that folder location? Also: why not just do s.WriteLine("@echo off"); instead of putting it into sText?

Comment: The file doesn't exist. If it doesn't, how can I check? Yeah I could put it all into write line but I just copied and pasted from another group of code and just used it that way.

Comment: How are you running the code above?  Is it running in a console app locally as you?  ASP.NET in IIS?

Comment: Yeah visual studios 2008 asp.net.. idk if it's IIS. I am running it locally

Comment: i pasted the code into testing.js and ran "cscript testing.js" from CMD.exe, and it worked as you'd expect...

Comment: @dandavis thank you for confirming.. what is the next step I should take to get this to work on my side..?

Comment: how are you running the file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by how am I running the file. All of this is being ran in visual studios 2008 though. And the code is supposed to work with a button so when I click on it, it should create the .bat file into the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, I think you're missing an s.Close();

Comment: I added the s.Close(); problem still exists.

Comment: I can't remember if 2008 runs locally as you or as IISAppPool.  In folder settings for c:\temp, add IISAppPool with write access to that folder.

Comment: May you kindly guide me through the process to add IISAppPool with write access into the folder? Thank you.

Comment: Sure.  Open up C drive in Windows Explorer.  Find temp and right click on it.  Select Properties.  In the new window, select the Security tab, then click Edit...  In new window, click Add, and search for IISAppPool.  Add it and make sure you click the checkbox next to write, and then save your changes.  Try re-running again and see if it creates the file.

Comment: Okay I followed you up until "search for IISAppPool. I typed it in and it couldn't find it. I also clicked on advanced and find now. And I don't see an IISAppPool..

Comment: Maybe it's Network Service.  Try adding it for Network Service